# How to find all path of elements of same name in an xml using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

In the following xml, I need to find all paths of 'elem' element which will be //root//abc//elem and //root//abc//xyz//elem.

```
        <root>    
            <abc>
                <elem>-144.00</elem>
            </abc>
            <abc>
                <elem>5.49</elem>
                <xyz>
                    <elem>Ravindra Kumar Gautam</elem>
                </xyz>
            </abc>
        </root>
```

Comment: That looks like an interesting task. I suggest you get started and come back when you have code to show and a question about your code.

Comment: What programming language are you using to do this?

Comment: Hi, i am using nodejs.

Comment: elem  must be on that levels -  /root/abc/elem and /root/abc/xyz/elem or you want elem on all lavels? Or on on levels under /root/abc/ ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the task we can reverse the pathes and see that under `elem` must be in second case `xyz` and further in both cases `abs` and `root`, and nothing upper. Write this on xpath 1.0 language

```
//elem[parent::xyz[parent::abc[parent::root[not(parent::*)]]] 
       or 
       parent::abc[parent::root[not(parent::*)]]]
```

Unfortunatly, i cant to write the  repeating part  of this sentence only once. But this affect only to beauty :)